# pstricks \rput text placement

Tags: pstricks

I am new to pstrick and want to use uput to add some axis labels. I compile the following example

```
% !TeX program = latex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
%\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1mm}
\psset{algebraic=true}
\begin{pspicture}(-10,10)(110,-110)
  \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none,linewidth=.5pt]{->}(0,0)(-2,2)(105,-105)
  \psdot*[dotstyle=|](50,0)
  \psdot*[dotstyle=|](86,0)
  \rput[0](86,5){\psframebox{$c$}}
  %\rput[0](0,-50){$EU$}    
  \psplot[plotstyle=line,linewidth=0.5pt]{0}{68}{x-68}
  \psplot[plotstyle=line,linewidth=0.5pt]{68}{100}{68-x}
  \psplot[plotstyle=line,linewidth=0.5pt]{0}{93}{x-93}
  \psplot[plotstyle=line,linewidth=0.5pt]{93}{100}{93-x}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

c should be put in the box, but is placed at the origin.[image: Compiled example]

Could you please help me?

Comment: it looks like that you view the dvi output. Run it with `xelatex` and it should work. Or use the route `latex->dives->ps2pdf` or use package `auto-pst-pdf` and `pdflatex`. See also http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput